# Unsingning a signed value Django Rest

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am using `web3.personal.sign(nonce, web3.eth.coinbase, callback);` to sign nonce at the front end but I am trying to build the backend in Django Rest.

Using this to unsign the signed nonce but getting an error:

```
from django.core import signing 

unsigned_value = signing.loads(signed_value)
```

error-

```
django.core.signing.BadSignature: No ":" found in value
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how to unsign this nonce?

Comment: "Signing" is not a standardized process.  You are assuming that the Ethereum internal signing algorithm is the same as the Django core internal igning algorithm.  I don't believe that is true.

Comment: @TimRoberts but django does not supports js web3 library so is there no way to implement that in django ?

Comment: https://github.com/Bearle/django-web3-auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by running JavaScript file with python using subprocess.

```
node filename.js arg1 arg2
```